# Update element of an array using aggregation pipeline in `update` operation

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested, mongodb-query

## Scenario

For the below document, I want to update the `status` of a specific **message** in the `messages` array:

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6079bab4f297df39a44609cb"),
    "title" : "Test messages of single user",
    "messages" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6079bab4f297df39a44609cc"),
            "body" : "Test 1",
            "status" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6079bab4f297df39a44609cd"),
            "body" : "Test 2",
            "status" : 1
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("6079bcf7c041b00ec4cebb9d"),
            "body" : "Hello I'm Sam",
            "status" : 1
        }
    ]
}]
```

1. Query **without aggregation pipeline** in update operation **updates the status in single message**.

Run below query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LWlZGU41rsn)

```
db.update(
  { 
    "_id": ObjectId("6079bab4f297df39a44609cb"), 
    "messages": { $elemMatch: { _id: ObjectId("6079bcf7c041b00ec4cebb9d") } }
  }, 
  {
    $set: { "messages.$.status": 2 }
  }
)
```

2. Query **with aggregation pipeline** in update operation **updates the status in all messages**

Run below query [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FlXDl6Hp4ZE)

```
db.update(
  { 
    "_id": ObjectId("6079bab4f297df39a44609cb"), 
    "messages": { $elemMatch: { _id: ObjectId("6079bcf7c041b00ec4cebb9d") } }
  }, 
  [
    {
      $set: { "messages.status": 2 }
    }
  ]
)
```

**MongoDB Version: 4.4**

**Note:** For some reason, I need to use the second query but I am not able to update the status of single message. It always update all the messages

## Question

1. Why is the second query updating status in all messages when I've selected the message that I want to update?
2. How can I update status of single message with aggregation pipeline (second query)?

It'll be helpful if you can share link for the query

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/VZHes8--O5O

Use [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

> The filtered positional operator $[] identifies the array elements that match the arrayFilters conditions for an update operation

```
db.collection.update(
 { "_id": ObjectId("6079bab4f297df39a44609cb") },
 { $set: { "messages.$[m].status": 2 } },
 { arrayFilters: [ { "m._id": ObjectId("6079bcf7c041b00ec4cebb9d") } ]
})
```

---

**Update**

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/GyBxksYKpmf

Use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/)

```
db.collection.update({
  "_id": ObjectId("6079bab4f297df39a44609cb"),
  "messages": {
    $elemMatch: {
      _id: ObjectId("6079bcf7c041b00ec4cebb9d")
    }
  }
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "messages": {
        $map: {
          input: "$messages",
          as: "m",
          in: {
            $cond: [
              { $eq: [ "$$m._id", ObjectId("6079bcf7c041b00ec4cebb9d") ] }, // condition
              { $mergeObjects: [ "$$m", { status: 2 } ] }, // true
              "$$m" // false
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)

[$mergeObjects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/)

Note- it's overkill in this case

Comment: I need to use the aggregation pipeline in update operation. Just like I mentioned in second query

Comment: What do you mean by `overkill`? Can you please explain?

Comment: @AbhishekPankar suppose I've 1000s `messages` $map will loop over every message and check condition.

Comment: Isn't there any other way then?

Comment: Not far from witchcraft... but works for me!  MongoDB is so great in many ways.  Less great in others.

Comment: finally the answer!! I was searching for it for so many days

Comment: for some cases the first option doesnt work and have to go with the second. just imagine how easy if positional operators also worked here :(